# how to avoid duplicate voice speech input in textfield in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, textfield

I have my app developed using LibGdx, I have a textfield in my stage which support English/Chinese input.

In my android phone, I have google voice-speech installed, but I found in my app, I always got duplicate voice-to-speech input if I don't stop recording. For example, if I press start record button, and say "how are you", if I don't press stop record button, my textfield may end up have "how are you how are you".

I remember when I use social network app, such as facebook, wechat, for voice-to-speech input, the duplicate won't happen. Any way that I can avoid this duplicate?